# Evenly distribute points along a path

Tags: geometry

I have a user defined path which a user has hand drawn - the distance between the points which make up the path is likely to be variant.

I would like to find a set of points along this path which are equally separated.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: A curved path, or a piecewise-linear path? (The first one is more difficult.)

Comment: a  piecewise-linear path

Comment: In case someone else finds this question after 7 years, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117660/how-to-generate-equispaced-interpolating-values) provided exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you measure distance along the path it is no different from a straight line.  If the length is $L$ and you want $n$ points (including the ends) you put a point at one end and every $\frac{L}{n-1}$ along the way.  If you measure distance as straight lines between the points there is no guarantee of a solution, but you could just start with this guess (or something a bit smaller) and "swing a compass" from each point, finding where it cuts the curve (could be more than once-this is problematic), and see how close to the end you wind up.  Then a one-dimensional rootfinder (the parameter is the length of the radius) will do as well as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an arc-length parametrization that you can sample uniformly. See http://groups.google.com/group/comp.graphics.algorithms/msg/c7025fd53b18db94 .

You probably need to smooth the input data before doing this. See for instance [Efficient Curve Fitting](http://jgt.akpeters.com/papers/Frisken08/). See also a [summary](http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~andyn/courses/tncg08/sketches/content/sketches/0360.pdf).

Comment: He said his path is piecewise linear, so I'm not sure how unit-speed applies.

Comment: @J.M., it certainly does apply because the lengths of each piece are likely to be different. You cannot simply sample each piece uniformly. OTOH, it's certainly much simpler to find an arc-length parametrization for a piecewise linear curve, though not entirely trivial.